# jquery toggle individually

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

My html is something like this:

```
<a class="tableheadlink" href="#">Impressions</a> <a href="#"><img src="images/table-sort.png" alt="" /></a>
<div class="filter-head">
    <form>
        <select name="website" class="rounded-all no-padding">
            <option value="opt1">&gt;</option>
            <option value="opt2">&lt;</option>
            <option value="opt3">=</option>
        </select>
        <input name="q" type="text" class="rounded-all small">
    </form>
</div>
```

jquery something like this:

```
        $(".filter-head").hide();
        $("a.tableheadlink").click(function(){
            $(".filter-head").toggle();
            return false;
        });
```

How do i tell it to toggle each instant of the html section individually? There is about 10 instances of it on the page and the toggle will just toggle all using my code.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the `.filter-head` you want [relative](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) to `this`, for example:

```
$(".filter-head").hide();
$("a.tableheadlink").click(function(){
    $(this).nextAll(".filter-head:first").toggle();
    return false;
});
```

What this does is go from `this` then uses [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) with your class selector and gets the [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) one it encounters to toggle.  The reason for [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) instead of [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) is that there is that other link in-between.

Comment: Thanks Nick. As a follow up, i've a very similar issue related to this question. I thought once i knew how this was done i could work out the rest but obviously not. Take a look here if you could http://jsfiddle.net/nYRqa/11/ The toggle div here is outside of the link so how would i select this? I've tried all the selectors you linked too but can't seem to work it out.... Appreciate the help mate.